# How to display suggestions in a textbox while searching?

Tags: codenameone

Can anybody has working code example using CN1 for a search text box, which displays suggestions dynamically while user types text into it. Please help.

Comment: Go for `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: @GrisHu is correct, I suggest posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**AutoCompleteTextView:** An editable text view that shows completion suggestions automatically while the user is typing. The list of suggestions is displayed in a drop down menu from which the user can choose an item to replace the content of the edit box with.

The drop down can be dismissed at any time by pressing the back key or, if no item is selected in the drop down, by pressing the enter/dpad center key.

The list of suggestions is obtained from a data adapter and appears only after a given number of characters defined in list.

For more detail explanation check [AutomCompleteTextView Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! But I am using Codename one platform to develop my App. I can use the above Native Android code in CN1 but then I need to implement Native code for each platform to get that functionality. Is there any working code using Codename one API?

Comment: I am not getting your question. What are you trying to say? @Arindam_4_Java

Comment: Hey Grishu kya 6 tu yar?

Comment: I am here only :) @PiYusHGuPtA

Comment: GrIsHu the example you have shared which uses Android code but I am using a Cross Platform Java technology to build mobile apps named 'Codename one'. The question is also tagged with Codename one and not Android. I hope its clear now :))